# Is the infinite union of decreasingly nested compact sets compact?

Tags: general-topology

The common counterexample that the infinite union of compact sets need not be compact is to take $A_n = [-n, n]$, whose infinite union $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. However, I was wondering if this is also true for infinite unions of decreasingly nested compact subsets (i.e. $C_n \supset C_{n+1} \supset C_{n+2} \supset ...$)?

What if they're also closed? Thanks.

Edit: I should have made this more explicit: what if we are taking $\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty C_n$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether the infinite *intersection* $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n$ is nonempty? or compact?

Comment: @BrianO No, why?

Comment: Because their union is $C_0$ and that's compact but the question isn't interesting.

Comment: Ah, right. I've edited my post. Apologies

Comment: Since the union is invariant under even infinite permutations of the sets, a decreasing and an increasing sequence are exactly the same. Just number them in the opposite order (that is, relabel $C_n$ as $C_{-n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Let $C_n = 
\begin{cases}
[n, -n+1]  & \text{for $n \le 0$}, \\
[0, 1/(n+1)] & \text{for $n > 0$}.
\end{cases}
$

Then $\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} C_n = \mathbb{R}$ again. However, $\bigcap_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} C_n = \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 2):

If your subsets are nested, then taking the union doesn't change the original compact set (since you don't add any new elements, as the subsets are nested inside the original one), and so the union is compact.

**Edit:**

If the union is over the integers instead of the naturals, then the answer is no, and you can see this by expanding the example you gave. Look at the following familiy of sets:
$$A_n=[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}], A_{-n}=[-n,n]$$
(You have a problem at $A_0$, but you can just define it to be $[-1,1]$). This family of sets has the exact same problem as before - the union is $\mathbb R$, which is not compact.

Comment: Apologies, I missed out a crucial part of the question. It's been edited now.

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer

Comment: Wouldn't your definition of $A_0$  and $A_1$not work because $A_{-1} = A_{0} = A_1$ (which goes against the decreasingly nested strict subset hypothesis)?

Comment: I assumed you also allow non-strict subsets. In this case, you can simply get rid of $A_0$ and $A_1$ if you wish, or change them slightly so that they give proper containment, Anyway, this won't change the idea behind the example - you can have intervals getting larger and larger as $n\rightarrow -\infty$, so it doesn't matter what happens for positive values of $n$.